# Unix - Delete a portion which matches a regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a log file and I am trying to tidy it up to use some data inside. 
I want to use something like `sed 's/foo//g'` except that instead of matching the word foo i want it to delete everything from foo until the next space.

I tried (without success):

`sed -e -- 's/(?<=foo)(.*)(?= )//g'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want it to delete everything from foo until the next space.

You can use:

```
sed 's/foo[^[:blank:]]*//g' file
```

`[^[:blank:]]` will match any character that is not a space and not a tab.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Pretty clever negation.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
foo\S*(?=\s)
```

`\S` is a non-whitespace character. It has a positive lookahead which isn't part of the match, so that you can delete the entire match. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QakV5r/1).

Edit: Actually, it's easier and better with a word boundary:

```
foo\S*\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QakV5r/2). Now `foobar` can be at the end of the line as well.